# How to make photos on my website load faster?

Tags: html, css, image, loading, photo

In my last project, I had problem with photos on my website. They were loading to long. User had to wait to see whole picture. I rescaled photos, but it made them pixelated on desktop, and  they were loading to long on smartphone.(basically the problem was with smartphones). Is there any other way to upload pohotos in html (than "`img src=""`;) or in css (than "`backgoround-image:url();`")?
What determines the speed of loading photos?

Comment: depends on how many images we are talking and how much efford you want to do. First at all, the image size in MB an the abndwidth determine the speed of image loading. Its also a question of what bandwidth your server provides and how many access it at the same time. One evry complicated thing you can do is, to add the images via CSS as background image. Thatw ay youc an use media queries to load either a high-resolution or low-resolution image depending on the screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important factor in image loading performance is the size, in bytes, of the image files you're loading.  It's easy in the world of ubiquitous high-resolution digital cameras to get multimegabyte high resolution images. They're suitable for printing.

There are plenty of tools in the world for downsampling images (reducing their width / height from, say 4096 / 3072  to 512 / 384. And if you're using JPEG images, your camera probably captures them with a very high JPEG quality, let's say 3.  Most tools, while downsampling the image, can also reduce the JPEG quality from 3 to something like 35.  When the input image needs five megabytes, it's not uncommon for the resulting image to need 60 kilobytes.

A downsampled and JPEG-reduced-quality image looks just fine on most web sites and will have an order of magnitude or more fewer bytes in it. There's your speed.

You didn't say anything about how you're serving your images, so it's hard to give you specific advice about how to do it.

Answer (score -3):

Try to resize image before using it.